# does flowplayer or jwplayer support the old VAST1.0 for ad serving?

Tags: jwplayer, flowplayer, openx, vast

I'm using revive adserver(the former OpenX) to crate inline video ad,
I'm able to get the VAST1.0 xml from revive ,the xml format like this:

```
<VideoAdServingTemplate>
<Ad id="pre-roll">
<InLine>...</InLine>
</Ad>
</VideoAdServingTemplate>
```

the revive guys said they won't support VAST2.0 +(https://www.revive-adserver.com/blog/can-revive-adserver-support-vast-2-0/)

so My question:
which video player is still supporting the old VAST1.0 for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW Player supports VAST 1.0 with the use of flash, but not for free. You must have a Platinum-tier account or higher to enable advertising. You will want to keep in mind flash is being deprecated in the major market share browsers later on this year. These links may be of help:
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1431638
https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/deprecation-flash/

Comment: thank for reply, yes I don't want to use flash too, does JW Player support mp4? or do u know any other video players that can support vast1.0 with mp4?

Comment: It's not about the player, it's about the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats